# Installed Debian package-list with version-numbers

Tags: bash, debian, package, version

I want to compare two Debian systems with respect to packages version numbers. For that I need a file listing of all installed packages like this:

```
a2ps    1:4.14-1.3
abiword 3.0.0-8+b1
acl     0.6.37-3+b1
...
```

I wrote a bash script (rather clumsy) that collects the required info, but I cannot make it write to a file. Can someone help me to fix this?

```
dpkg --get-selections  \
 | grep "\binstall\b" \
 | sed 's/\(^[A-Za-z0-9\.\-\_]*\).*/\1/' \
 | while read i ; \
    do `echo $i` `apt-cache policy $i \
    | grep Install \
    | sed 's/ *Installed: *\([A-Za-z0-9\.\-\_]*\)/\1/' `\
 ; done
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dpkg-query --show -f '${Package}\t${Version}\n' > out.txt
```

Comment: I could not imagine that something like this did not exist, but did not find it. Thank you.